# Translating COM objects (or possibly XMLHTTP) in Coldfusion to C#

Tags: c#, xml, com, coldfusion

I've been converting a bunch of files from Coldfusion to C#, and all has been going swimmingly until now. I'm pretty much learning ColdFusion as I go, and I barely ever write in C# so I'm stuck here. Can anybody help explain how I would go about translating this chunk of code into C#?

```
<cfobject type="COM" action="Create" name="objServerXMLHttp" class="msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0">
<cfset objServerXMLHttp.open("POST", "http://URL", True , "Me.User", "Me.Password")>
<cfset objServerXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")>
<cfset objServerXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("charset", "utf-8")>
<cfset objServerXMLHttp.send("#XMLRequest#")>
<cfset thread = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.Thread")>
```

For some background, I'm basically just taking info from a database, surrounding it with XML tags in a string, creating an XML file out of the string, and now here I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct translation is easy in C# 4.0 (VS2010) with the *dynamic* keyword:

```
        dynamic objServerXMLHttp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0"));
        objServerXMLHttp.open("POST", "http://chrdevweb:8080/mellibase/webservice/rest", true, "Me.User", "Me.Password");
        objServerXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        objServerXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("charset", "utf-8");
        objServerXMLHttp.send("#XMLRequest#");
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting an XML exception:
...SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Any suggestions? That "dynamic" keyword is very interesting.

Comment: +1 - I didn't think you wanted a literal translation, just the same functionality... in which case this is word-for-word a translation...

Answer (score 1):

So just to break it down as to what this coldfusion code is doing (which you probably know anyway):

1. It is instantiating an object type msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP in memory.
2. It is then using that object to construct an XML document.
3. It is then sending that (via HTTP POST) to the URL: http://chrdevweb:8080/mellibase/webservice/rest
4. And lastly, it seems to instantiate a java object (not sure its related).

So in asp.net using c#, the post code would like so:

```
   HttpWebRequest request=null;
   Uri uri = new Uri(url);
   request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
   request.Method = "POST";
   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

   using(Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
   {
      UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
      byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
      writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   }

   string result=string.Empty;
   using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
   {
       using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
       {
          using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (responseStream,   Encoding.UTF8))
          {
            result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
          }
       }
   }
```

The result variable in the end would hold your response. The 'url' is the url you are posting to, and 'postData' is your xml string.

To construct the XML doc, you can use XMLdocument in c#, or you can just put a string together.

PS: this is untested, so there may be a syntax error somewhere :)